# Visual Basic How do you Reuse Classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I wanted to know if it is possible to reuse a class I created in one application in another application.

Basically I created a test program and once I got all the components working I created a class for it and well I want to use the class in another program, how can I do this?

I'm a nub when it comes to programming so if you can make it as easy to understand a possible I would be greatful.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of common ways, depending on how you want to organize your code/projects:

1. Place the class in a class library project and reference that project in your other projects.
2. Place the class in a class library, compile it, reference the resulting DLL in your other projects.
3. Copy the class file to another project.  (This results in duplicating the class across projects, but there do exist situations that call for this.)
4. Reference the project which contains the class in another project.  (If the project being referenced is an application, this is unfavorable.  It would work, but it's poor code organization.)

(1) is my personal preference, I like to have many projects in my solutions which reference each other's code directly rather than referencing compiled DLLs.  A lot of people prefer (2) for their own code, not wanting to keep so many projects open all over the place and rather deal with a one-time compiled DLL.  It's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: For option (4) do you mean adding the class file to the project but without moving the file? I.e. use [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx) to refer to a .vb file that's outside the project directory? I don't think you can reference an application *project* from another project.

Comment: @MarkJ: I know you can at least reference a web application (or web service) project from another project.  At my last job they did such terrible things in their code.  You may be right though, I've never tried it with a Windows/Console application.  Still, options 1 and 2 are preferred.  That link option sounds pretty good.  It just comes down to how the developer wants to organize his code, really.

Comment: I think referencing a web service project would just mean that your code called the web service... which sounds absolutely fine, doesn't it?? I've not heard of referencing a web application from another project. Is that possible?

Comment: @MarkJ: It's possible.  In a recent job we had a legacy outsourced application where a WebForms Application would have a Web Reference to a plain old SOAP web service application, but _also_ had a project reference to it so it should use its internal classes (ones not included in the Web Reference, such as return types).  It was a mess to say the least, but it was definitely possible.

Comment: Yuk! That is interesting... but I will now try to forget that it's possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have that class in an assembly.

Make a new project - a Windows Class Library. Put your class to be re-used in there.

Reference this project or built assembly from your application(s).

You'll be able to then `Imports` the namespace in your consuming applications. Naming becomes important here, but try it out, and see how it works for you.

Comment: Thanks The class just contained a bunch of range finding functions for searching a grid. Kinda like a rook in a chess game. I was making workin on a pathfinding program. Lol i know i shouldnt make my own when there are plenty already out there, but i love getting my hands dirty. Needless to say it failed. i moves to the location and aviods obsticals and even other peices moving about the grid but it likes to take really unatural routes often time circling its from point before it starts moving to its target location.  Anyway don't know if that to far off topic but thanks for the advice.